# Auto adjust the last menu div with floats

Tags: css, css-float

I've searching for the answer but none with floats in left and right, so isn't working with table-cell.
I want to the last menu div auto fit the layout, the code:

```
<div class="menu2">
<div class="esq"><img src="imgs/left-mainnav.png" width="10" height="60" alt=""/></div>
<div class="dir"><img src="imgs/right-mainnav.png" width="10" height="60" alt=""/></div>
  <div class="botao1" style="border-left:1px solid #CCCCCC">Content</div>
  <div class="botao1">Content</div>
  <div class="botao1">Content</div>
  <div class="botao1">Content</div>
  <div class="botao1">Content</div>
  <div class="botao1">Content</div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.menu2 {
    height: 63px;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: -11px;
    margin-left: -11px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.esq {
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    width: 10px;
}
.dir {
    float: right;
    height: 60px;
    width: 10px;
}
.botao1 {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 149px;
    border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: please be more clear. Are you trying to make the last items div have a different padding?

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if my answer was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You are probably after some thing like this:

```css
.menu2 {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dir{
  order: 999;
}

.item {
  width: 149px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  text-align: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.item p{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.item:last-child{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.esq, .dir {
  width: 10px;
  background-image: url( "http://placehold.it/10x60/E8117F" );
}
```

```html
<div class="menu2">
  <div class="item esq"></div>
  <div class="item dir"></div>
  <div class="item botao1"><p>Content</p></div>
  <div class="item botao1"><p>Content</p></div>
  <div class="item botao1"><p>Content</p></div>
</div>
```